# std::vector does strange thing

Tags: c++, stdvector

I'm working on a function that reads a file, stores every line whose starting with a colon, and removes every dash contained in the string.
Every time this kind of line is found, push_back() is used to store it in a vector.
The problem is that, every time push_back() is used, all the elements in the vector take the value of the last one. I don't understand why it happens. Here's the code :

```
 string listContent;
 size_t dashPos;
 vector<char*>cTagsList;
 while(!SFHlist.eof())
 {
    getline(SFHlist, listContent);
    if(listContent[0] == ':')
    {
        listContent.erase(0, 1);
        dashPos = listContent.rfind("-", string::npos);
        while(dashPos != string::npos)
        {
            listContent.pop_back();
            dashPos = listContent.rfind("-", string::npos);
        }
        char* c_listContent = (char*)listContent.c_str();
        cTagsList.push_back(c_listContent);
    }
 }
```

I first thought it was a problem with the end of the file but aborting the searching process before reaching this point gives the same results.

Comment: First of all, [`while (!eof())` is wrong.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) Second, casting the result of `c_str` to `char *` is very bad. Third, that pointer is invalid as soon as you modify the string, which happens right after. Use a vector of `std::string`. Anyway, you're not removing every dash, you're removing everything after and including the first dash. Use `std::remove` and pair it with `erase`.

Comment: Do *not* store the results of `c_str`! Instead, just make `std::vector<std::string> cTagsList;` instead and just `cTagsList.push_back(listContent);`

Comment: use char* only when dealing with pure c, you have strings in c++

Comment: besides other comments, don't use char*, use std::string and you don't have to think too much

Comment: Well, thanks for the help. As i need a char array (because of ncurses in fact) i think i'll use a vector of string and then convert it to char, this should do the trick

Comment: you can get every single character using the subscript operator my_string[index], after all a string is an array of chars

Answer (score 2):

the c_str()-method of [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) states:

> The pointer returned may be invalidated by further calls to other member functions that modify the object.

If you're allowed to use a std::vector< std::string > instead of the vector of char*, you're fine since there would be always a copy of the std::string listContent pushed into the vector, ie.

```
std::string listContent;
 size_t dashPos;
 std::vector<std::string>cTagsList;
 while(!SFHlist.eof())
 {
    getline(SFHlist,listContent);
    if(listContent[0]==':')
    {
        listContent.erase(0,1);
        dashPos = listContent.rfind("-",string::npos);
        while(dashPos!=string::npos)
        {
            listContent.pop_back();
            dashPos = listContent.rfind("-",string::npos);
        }
        cTagsList.push_back(listContent);
    }
 }
```

*(I haven't tested it)*

Comment: As i replied to the first post, i need a char, but i'll try to get it by converting a std::vector<std::string> to a char, thanks for the help

Comment: @Faeralis blade already pointed out the [] operator of std::string which provides random access to every character in the string and what you can do alternatively is to use .c_str() as you did before, but on the strings already stored in the vector